# Where do I find out about the details and reasons for the patches applied to a package?

Tags: package-management

I am trying to build a package and I am having a problem building it.  One (or more) of the patches to doxygen installed with 12.04.1 (Precise), 1.7.4-3 causes doxygen to NOT run my filter script over by Tcl files, if the file is named with an extension of .tcl (the normal extension for Tcl files). If the extension is something else, like .src, the filter is run as expected.  I use .tcl for library or helper files that are explictly sources and .src for 'main' programs that are not.  (Yes, I have the proper file name patterns, etc. in the Doxyfiles -- my whole package builds just fine under CentOS 5 and CentOS 6, and under CentOS 5, I am even using an RPM I built of doxygen 1.7.4 (basically an unpatched version).  When I build doxygen manually *without* the Ubuntu/Debian patches under Ubuntu 12.04.1, it also works correctly.  The *installed* version does not work correctly.  I think one (or more?) of the patches breaks something in doxygen.  The changelog is not very enlightening.

I will be creating a trivial package that illustrates the problem tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the Precise default version of `doxygen` is `1.7.6.1-2ubuntu1`, as noted at [Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=doxygen&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all), so I'm not sure why you mention 1.7.4-3, as that is the 11.10 [Oneiric default version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=doxygen&searchon=names&suite=oneiric&section=all). I should check whether you really are on Precise, or have upgraded properly.

The version you are using still has the `doxygen_direct_dot_run.diff` patch applied, while the actual version for Precise, (1.7.6.1-2ubuntu1) doesn't have it applied. So using the real Precise version might solve some of the problems as it has other patches too. There aren't any current bugs describing your issue at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/doxygen), so it could be a new one.

**More generally, patches and changelogs**

When you download the source (`apt-get source doxygen`), you can see which patches are applied (for doxygen in Precise):

```
dpkg-source: info: applying manpages.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying dot-config.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying gcc-g.diff
dpkg-source: info: applying doxygen-jquery.patch
```

**However**, you can also download the program's source without the patches being applied or the packages unpacked:

```
apt-get source doxygen --download-only
```

(You could build the package and omit some of the patches if you wanted to.)

If you have used the `--download-only` switch to `apt-get source` you will have 2 packages and a signature file. You can unpack `doxygen_1.7.6.1-2ubuntu1.debian.tar.gz` to view the patches, changelog, and rules (not all the patches in the patches folder will actually be used).

The changelog will contain references to the patches and will always include the Debian (#number) or Launchpad (LP: #number) of the bug, and this can be searched on the respective bug trackers. That is the best way to find more information on the patches than in the very brief changelog.

Examples from the doxygen source changelog:

> Don't apply doxygen_direct_dot_run.diff.  Closes: #618125.

Now #618125 is the debian ticket, so you can search bugs by number at [debian](http://www.debian.org/Bugs/) and
find more details.

> Add multiarch metadata to satisfy cross-dependencies (LP: #971739)

Similarly, to find more information you would search for this bug at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/) by entering the number.

More generally, you could also go to [patches.ubuntu.com](https://patches.ubuntu.com/):

> These patches are generated daily and contain the differences between an Ubuntu source package and the equivalent version of the same source in Debian.

Apart from discussion on the bug thread itself, on forums, or on irc channels, these avenues of investigation are about the most you can use to find out about the rationale for patches.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the problem is not Ubuntu, but doxygen itself.  It appears that doxygen 1.7.6.1 is broken in that it is not honoring filter settings for files named *.tcl, but going ahead and using its own internal parser, which is not working for my comments, since they were written with *my* filter in mind and were written before doxygen had any notion of dealing with Tcl source.  I will have to downgrade the version of doxygen on my Ubuntu build boxes and go bother the Doxygen people about this problem.